# Why no one should perform any Puja if someone from their family suffering from Chicken Pox?

Tags: belief

I got chicken pox in November, My mother cancelled her whole Karthika Masam pujas

Why no one should perform any Puja if someone from their family suffering from Chicken Pox?

Comment: I also got chicken pox but in my family only i was not allowed to go to temple but my family members go to temple

Comment: The reason might not be religious at all. But it may be religious too. So did u ask ur mother why she cancelled the Puja? Did she give any further reasons?